# Print a number in c digit by digit

Tags: c

i have number `5678`

i want display number as below

```
5678
678
78
8
```

how can i do in c??

i done this

```
int n = 5678;

for(int i=n; i >= 1; --i)
{
    for(int j=1; j <= i; ++j)
  {

       print("%d",j);

  }

   print("\n")
}
```

Comment: Show us your code, if you have tried one.

Comment: Your question vs. example doesn't make sense. You're not trying to reverse a number here.

Comment: This is very simple, please try without any help

Answer (score 5):

First *"stringify"* the int, then you can use a string pointer for this:

```
int main()
{
    int n = 5678;
    char *str_p, str[10];//declare a char pointer, and an array of 10 chars
    sprintf(str, "%d", n);//initializes str to {'5','6','7','8','\0'}
    str_p = &str[0];//init pointer to start of string, str_p = str; works, too
    while(*str_p != '\0')
    {//while pointer doesn't point to end of string:
        printf("%s\n", str_p);//print string str_p points to
        str_p++;//shift pointer, to point to next char in string
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The resulting output, as you can see [in this codepad](http://codepad.org/euVSqvwo) is:

```
5678
678
78
8
```

Quite easy, really.
The trick is `str_p++`. At first, when I was learning about pointers, I found this quite confusing. But it really is quite simple. Think of a pointer as that red plastic square thing on a calendar: you slide it over whatever date it happens to be that day:

```
MAY:
_____________________________
|   |   |   |   |   |___|   |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 ||6|| 7 |
|___|___|___|___|___|---|___|
```

This means it's the sixth of may. Right, if we translate this to a pointer + array in C we'd have something like:

```
int may[31] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...};
int *today = &may[5];//zero indexed
```

The action of sliding the red square thing to the next day (today + 1 == tomorrow) is written, logically, like this:

```
today++;//or today += 1
```

This is to say:

```
          today + 1: [] =>[]//shift the red square-thingy
_____________________________
|   |   |   |   |   |   |___|
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 ||7||
|___|___|___|___|___|___|---|
```

So if I then were to write:

```
today--;
```

the same logic applies, and today points back to 6... go to the store, buy one of these calendars if you feel the need to visualize this...
Suppose you want to change the value that is being pointed to by a pointer? Well, sticking to the same analogy (of a slider over some value), you'd have to use your one hand to hold that slider in place, and with the other hand, you can then work on what's underneath it. In your code this is reflected by the inderection `*` operator. Think of it as a pin, to hold the pointer in place while you work on whatever it points to:

```
(*today)++;//or *today++;, both operators have the same precedence
```

It really, really, really is that simple... Well, no it's not :) but 9/10 times you're using pointers, this way of thinking works

BTW: using `str_p = str;` is, I think more logical, and a tad more efficient, but the compiler probably optimizes both statements to the same thing. Still [Here's another codepad, to prove both do the same thing](http://codepad.org/fealQ9Te)

And now, to end, a more generic approach, that'll work with numbers of variable length, dynamically allocating memory required for the string, and freeing it again:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, len, n = 5678;
    char *str_p = NULL;
    int digitCount(int in);
    len = digitCount(n);//how many chars do we need to allocate?
    str_p = calloc(len, sizeof(char));//allocate string, calloc inits memory to 0
    len--;//avoid printing empty string at the end
    sprintf(str_p, "%d", n);//set string in memory
    for(i=0;i<len;++i) printf("%s\n", str_p + i);//print string, increment pointer by i
    free(str_p);//deallocate string memory
    return 0;
}

int digitCount(int in)
{
    int count = 1;//1 for 0 terminating char
    while(in)
    {//as long as in/10 (being an int, this will eventually become 0 ==> false)
        in /= 10;
        ++count;//add 1 digit to count
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation on pointers. Quite handy

Comment: well I can't upvote twice right!!!

Comment: @rookieB: nips... indeed you can't... thx for the upvote, sorry for the rep-whoring :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int reversDigits(int num)
{
    int rev_num = 0;
    while(num > 0)
    {
        rev_num = rev_num*10 + num%10;
        num = num/10;
    }
    return rev_num;
}

int main()
{
int num=5678;
int rev=reversDigits(num);
while(rev)
{

printf("%d "reversDigits(rev));
printf("\n");
rev=rev/10;

}
}
```

Comment: What about `printf("%d\n", reverseDigits(num));`, without the loop. Your reverseDigits function will return 8765 anyway

Comment: num=num/10; this will remove the first digit of the number.

Comment: try this yourself.If it works upvote .

Comment: I _know_ what your code does, but try `printf("%d\n", reverseDigits(num));` yourself, and you'll see that those loops you've written in the main function are pointless. Especially since you're calling `num = reverseDigits(num)` and then `printf("%d\n", reverseDigits(num))`. Reverse something twice, and you end up wit the same thing: 123 -> reverse -> 321 -> reverse -> 123.

Comment: this will work..I just edited.  
Pls upvote if i am ryt.

Comment: You haven't even tested this code... you're still reversing the number too many times, and you've got a syntax error. Use codepad to test, it shouldn't even compile. Plus, even if this did work, I wouldn't upvote it, because IMO, this answer is less efficient than mine. My answer only requires 2 functions. None of which you'll have to write yourself.