# function call using pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers, compiler-errors

Can anyone explain me why am I getting the error

> cannot convert int ** to int* of argument1

I have seen all the stack overflow answers but did not  find the way to solve my problem. My code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int* sum(int,int*);

int main()
{
    int a=5;
    int *b;

    *b=6;
    int *res;

    res=sum(a,&b);
    printf("\n%d\n%d\n",a,*b);
    printf("%d",*res);
}

int* sum(int x,int *y)
{
    x=x+1;
    *y=*y+3;
    return (&y);
}
```

This is a basic problem but I am finding it hard to solve the error.

Comment: `I have seen all the stackoverflow answers but couldnt find the way to solve my problem`...sorry, somehow I don't believe that. :-)

Comment: Is that the error you got when compiling and running your code? I don't get that error.

Comment: Somehow none of the 5 answers so far mentioned this, but `int *b; *b = 6;` is an error because you write through an uninitialized pointer.  You must make `b` point somewhere before writing `*b = 6`. (or perhaps, change `b` to `int b;`)

Comment: `b` is of the type `int *`, (as Matt said: you need to initialize it, before dereferencing it to avoid UB)passing `&b` to `sum`, you're passing a pointer to a variable of the type `int *`, thus you're passing `int **`, just loose the `&` operator both in the call and the return statements, and you're good to go

Comment: sourav ghosh iam newbie in pointers and I couldnt understand the answers i found in stackoverflow .......sorry if my question seemed silly :)

Answer (score 5):

> res=sum(a,&b);

Here b is already a pointer(*an unallocated integer pointer which may lead to undefined behaviour*).So &b is of type int **. So pass only b.

```
res(a,b);
```

After that you return &y which is also of int** type change it to y (of type int *)if you want to return the address.

```
return y;
```

Comment: thanks sourav kanta :) ...Iam newbie in pointers..so iam very much confused  with the concepts ..can u please suggest me any sites so that i can improve my skils .....thank you :)

Comment: @shweta: [maybe this helps](https://eliasvo.wordpress.com/2014/11/15/pointers-are-easy/), it's a tad basic, but it tries to explain and help prevent the major pitfalls. Pointers really aren't that hard if you know how [a sliding calendar works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20114877/1230836), to be fair, pointers can be as difficult as you want them to be, but the basics are pretty straightforward

Answer (score 3):

In your case,

```
 int* sum(int x,int *y)
```

function accepts an `int`, an `int *` and finally returns an `int *`. Now, inside the function definition, you're writing

```
return (&y);
```

here. `y` is `int *`, so `&y` produces `int **`, which is wrong, as per the defined return type[e of the function.

change

```
 return (&y);
```

to

```
return y;
```

as you're returning an `int *`, and `y` is already one.

Next, the same kind of *conceptual* issue with the function call also. Instead of `res=sum(a,&b);`, you need to pass `b` only, as it's already a pointer.

Also, please notice,

1. the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.
2. `return` is not a function. You *usually* don't need a parenthesis around it's expression, specially, when using a variable name *only* as the expression.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone explain me why am I getting the error

Going over your code piece for piece:

```
int a=5;       /* initializes a to value 5        */
int *b;        /* declares pointer b              */

*b=6;          /* OPS, segfault here              */
int *res;      /* declares pointer res            */

res=sum(a,&b); /* assigning to the address of res */
```

The statement `*b = 6;` is wrong, you should not do that. You are trying to assign the value `6` to a pointer that is not dynamically allocated, and you haven't set it to point to any address yet.

What you should do is, make the pointer point to the address of a variable first, for example:

```
int c = 3;
int *b = &c; /* create a pointer 'b' and make that
                pointer point to the address of c */
*b = 6; /* OK */
```

Notice the difference in appearance between initializing `int *b = &c;`, and declaring and then assigning `b = &c`:

```
int *b; /* declaring a pointer 'b'                 */
b = &c; /* make that pointer point to address of c */
```

Next, you create a pointer variable 'res' and you try to assign the return value of sum to the address of res:

```
int *res;         /* declaring pointer 'res' */
res = sum(a, &b); /* OPS, 'b' is a pointer   */
```

Looking at the function 'sum', you are trying to make parameter `int *y` point to the address of `b`, but the way to do that with pointers is simply to omit the `&`, therefore passing only `b`: `sum(a, b);`

Now, the return value of `sum` is:

```
int* sum(int x,int *y) /*
   ^ sum returns a pointer to int */
```

And according to your code, you want to assign the result of function `sum` to the *address* of `res`, therefore you want to assign the *address* of `y` to the *address* of `res`:

```
res=sum(a,b); /* calling function sum */

int* sum(int x,int *y) /* 'y' points to address of b */
{
    x=x+1;
    *y=*y+3;
    return y; /* returning the address */
}
```

When sum returns, `res` points to the same *address* as `y` and `b`.

With pointers assign the address to the address of another pointer, example:

```
/* a and c are int's */
int *x = &a;
int *y = &c;
x = &y; /* wrong */
```

While this is correct:

```
int *x = &a;
int *y = &c;
x = y;  /* ok */
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `y` is an `int* y` (pointer to `int`), then `&y` is an `int**` (pointer to `int*` or pointer to pointer to `int`), but your function (`sum`) must return `int*`, not `int**`. You just change `return &y` to `return y` to fix this.